# Java Run time IncompatibleClassChangeError - tibco

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, build, tibco

I have a java web service which is implemented using springs , (SOAP) .. 
we use TIBCO to deploy the service. 
right now , I'm with a task to update something called as service-monitoring (specific to my org , it stores request and  response in  a web-page) , so anyway , When i update the service monitoring jar from 1.3.3 to 2.1 I'M getting **IncompatibleClassChangeError** at run time , when I hit the SOAP request ( this error is in the response body).
I've tried multiple things taking suggestions from people in the org ..

I'll attach the MANIFEST.MF file .. did my part of the research , it seems that there is issue with jars in the project (different version of it).. tried with multiple combination of different versions  of jars , still no use please help me what to do next ..

here is my MANIFEST.MF

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Eligibility
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.Company.member.eligibility
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/getmembeligbean-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,
 lib/getmembeligimpl-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,
 lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar,
 lib/asm-1.5.3.jar,
 lib/asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar,
 lib/cglib-2.1_3.jar,
 lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar,
 lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar,
 lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar,
 lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
 lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
 lib/dozer-5.0.jar,
 lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar,
 lib/jta.jar,
 lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar,
 lib/org.Company.dao.membercontractlookup.uhg.jar,
 lib/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar,
 lib/ehcache-1.2.3.jar,
 lib/hibernate3.jar,
 lib/ojdbc14_g.jar,
 lib/tdgssconfig.jar,
 lib/terajdbc4.jar,
 lib/commons-codec-1.1.jar,
 lib/icu4j-4_2_1.jar,
 lib/jasypt-1.6.jar,
 lib/org.company.wsdl.Member.eligibility.GetMemberPortType-service-interface.jar,
 lib/org.company.wsdl.Member.eligibility.GetMemberPortType-service-beans.jar,
 lib/jms-1.1.jar,
 lib/tibcrypt-5.1.jar,
 lib/tibemsd-sec-5.1.jar,
 lib/tibjms-5.1.jar,
 lib/tibjmsadmin-5.1.jar,
 lib/tibjmsapps-5.1.jar,
 lib/tibrvjms-5.1.jar,
 lib/aspectjrt.jar,
 lib/aspectjweaver.jar,
 lib/ess-utils-1.3.5.jar,
 lib/GLSClient-2.0.0.jar,
 lib/GLSClientBean-2.0.0.jar,
 lib/guava-11.0.2.jar,
 lib/service-monitor-beans-2.1.0.jar,
 lib/service-monitor-2.1.0.jar,
 lib/spring-aop-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-asm-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-context-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-expression-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-jdbc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-orm-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring-tx-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar,
 lib/global-xsd-2.1.0.jar,
 lib/xstream-1.3.1.jar,
 lib/commons-configuration-1.8.jar,
 lib/GetMemberBeans-3.12.0.jar,
 lib/org.company.wsdl.Member.eligibility.GetMemberPortType-service-   beans_src.jar,
 lib/org.company.wsdl.Member.eligibility.GetMemberPortType-service-interface_src.jar
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Export-Package: META-INF,
 META-INF.maven.commons-beanutils.commons-beanutils,
 META-INF.maven.commons-collections.commons-collections,
 META-INF.maven.commons-lang.commons-lang,
 META-INF.maven.commons-logging.commons-logging,
 META-INF.maven.log4j.log4j,
 META-INF.maven.org.dozer.dozer,
 META-INF.maven.org.jasypt.jasypt,
 antlr,
 antlr.ASdebug,
 antlr.actions.cpp,
 antlr.actions.csharp,
 antlr.actions.java,
 antlr.actions.python,
 antlr.build,
 antlr.collections,
 antlr.collections.impl,
 antlr.debug,
 antlr.debug.misc,
 antlr.preprocessor,
 com.ibm.icu,
 com.ibm.icu.impl,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.data,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt42b,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt42b.brkitr,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt42b.coll,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt42b.rbnf,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt42b.translit,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.duration,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.duration.impl,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.duration.impl.data,
 com.ibm.icu.impl.locale,
 com.ibm.icu.lang,
 com.ibm.icu.math,
 com.ibm.icu.text,
 com.ibm.icu.util,
 com.mchange,
 com.mchange.lang,
 com.mchange.util,
 com.mchange.v1,
 com.mchange.v1.db,
 com.mchange.v1.db.sql,
 com.mchange.v1.identicator,
 com.mchange.v1.io,
 com.mchange.v1.lang,
 com.mchange.v1.util,
 com.mchange.v1.xml,
 com.mchange.v2,
 com.mchange.v2.async,
 com.mchange.v2.beans,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.filter,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.mbean,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.subst,
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.util,
 com.mchange.v2.cfg,
 com.mchange.v2.cfg.junit,
 com.mchange.v2.coalesce,
 com.mchange.v2.codegen,
 com.mchange.v2.codegen.bean,
 com.mchange.v2.codegen.intfc,
 com.mchange.v2.debug,
 com.mchange.v2.encounter,
 com.mchange.v2.holders,
 com.mchange.v2.io,
 com.mchange.v2.lang,
 com.mchange.v2.log,
 com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging,
 com.mchange.v2.log.log4j,
 com.mchange.v2.management,
 com.mchange.v2.naming,
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool,
 com.mchange.v2.ser,
 com.mchange.v2.sql,
 com.mchange.v2.sql.filter,
 com.mchange.v2.util,
 com.ncr.teradata,
 com.teradata.jdbc,
 com.teradata.jdbc.interfaces,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.console,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastexport,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.monitor,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.dbmetadata,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.util,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.ifsupport,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.logging,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.parcel,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine,
 com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util,
 com.teradata.jdbc.resource,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jalgapi,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jgssp2gss,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jgssp2ldap,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jgssp2td1,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jgssp2td2,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jgssspi,
 com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss,
 javax.transaction,
 javax.transaction.xa,
 javax.xml.stream,
 javax.xml.stream.events,
 javax.xml.stream.util,
 net.sf.cglib.beans,
 net.sf.cglib.core,
 net.sf.cglib.proxy,
 net.sf.cglib.reflect,
 net.sf.cglib.transform,
 net.sf.cglib.transform.hook,
 net.sf.cglib.transform.impl,
 net.sf.cglib.util,
 net.sf.ehcache,
 net.sf.ehcache.bootstrap,
 net.sf.ehcache.config,
 net.sf.ehcache.constructs.asynchronous,
 net.sf.ehcache.constructs.blocking,
 net.sf.ehcache.constructs.concurrent,
 net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web,
 net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter,
 net.sf.ehcache.distribution,
 net.sf.ehcache.event,
 net.sf.ehcache.hibernate,
 net.sf.ehcache.store,
 net.sf.ehcache.util,
 oracle.core.lmx,
 oracle.core.lvf,
 oracle.jdbc,
 oracle.jdbc.connector,
 oracle.jdbc.driver,
 oracle.jdbc.internal;x-internal:=true,
 oracle.jdbc.oci,
 oracle.jdbc.oracore,
 oracle.jdbc.pool,
 oracle.jdbc.rowset,
 oracle.jdbc.util,
 oracle.jdbc.xa,
 oracle.jdbc.xa.client,
 oracle.jpub.runtime,
 oracle.net.TNSAddress,
 oracle.net.ano,
 oracle.net.aso,
 oracle.net.jndi,
 oracle.net.mesg,
 oracle.net.nl,
 oracle.net.nl.mesg,
 oracle.net.ns,
 oracle.net.nt,
 oracle.net.resolver,
 oracle.security.o3logon,
 oracle.sql,
 oracle.sql.converter,
 oracle.sql.converter_xcharset,
 org.apache.commons.beanutils,
 org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters,
 org.apache.commons.beanutils.expression,
 org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale,
 org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters,
 org.apache.commons.codec,
 org.apache.commons.codec.base64,
 org.apache.commons.codec.binary,
 org.apache.commons.codec.language,
 org.apache.commons.collections,
 org.apache.commons.collections.bag,
 org.apache.commons.collections.bidimap,
 org.apache.commons.collections.buffer,
 org.apache.commons.collections.collection,
 org.apache.commons.collections.comparators,
 org.apache.commons.collections.functors,
 org.apache.commons.collections.iterators,
 org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue,
 org.apache.commons.collections.list,
 org.apache.commons.collections.map,
 org.apache.commons.collections.set,
 org.apache.commons.lang,
 org.apache.commons.lang.builder,
 org.apache.commons.lang.enum,
 org.apache.commons.lang.enums,
 org.apache.commons.lang.exception,
 org.apache.commons.lang.math,
 org.apache.commons.lang.mutable,
 org.apache.commons.lang.text,
 org.apache.commons.lang.time,
 org.apache.commons.logging,
 org.apache.commons.logging.impl,
 org.apache.log4j,
 org.apache.log4j.chainsaw,
 org.apache.log4j.config,
 org.apache.log4j.helpers,
 org.apache.log4j.jdbc,
 org.apache.log4j.jmx,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5.config,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5.util,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.configure,
 org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.images,
 org.apache.log4j.net,
 org.apache.log4j.nt,
 org.apache.log4j.or,
 org.apache.log4j.or.jms,
 org.apache.log4j.or.sax,
 org.apache.log4j.spi,
 org.apache.log4j.varia,
 org.apache.log4j.xml,
 org.dom4j,
 org.dom4j.bean,
 org.dom4j.datatype,
 org.dom4j.dom,
 org.dom4j.dtd,
 org.dom4j.io,
 org.dom4j.jaxb,
 org.dom4j.rule,
 org.dom4j.rule.pattern,
 org.dom4j.swing,
 org.dom4j.tree,
 org.dom4j.util,
 org.dom4j.xpath,
 org.dom4j.xpp,
 org.dozer,
 org.dozer.cache,
 org.dozer.classmap,
 org.dozer.config,
 org.dozer.converters,
 org.dozer.event,
 org.dozer.factory,
 org.dozer.fieldmap,
 org.dozer.jmx,
 org.dozer.loader,
 org.dozer.loader.annotation,
 org.dozer.loader.dsl,
 org.dozer.loader.xml,
 org.dozer.propertydescriptor,
 org.dozer.spring,
 org.dozer.stats,
 org.dozer.util,
 org.hibernate,
 org.hibernate.action,
 org.hibernate.bytecode,
 org.hibernate.bytecode.cglib,
 org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist,
 org.hibernate.bytecode.util,
 org.hibernate.cache,
 org.hibernate.cache.entry,
 org.hibernate.cfg,
 org.hibernate.classic,
 org.hibernate.collection,
 org.hibernate.connection,
 org.hibernate.context,
 org.hibernate.criterion,
 org.hibernate.dialect,
 org.hibernate.dialect.function,
 org.hibernate.dialect.lock,
 org.hibernate.engine,
 org.hibernate.engine.loading,
 org.hibernate.engine.query,
 org.hibernate.engine.query.sql,
 org.hibernate.engine.transaction,
 org.hibernate.event,
 org.hibernate.event.def,
 org.hibernate.exception,
 org.hibernate.hql,
 org.hibernate.hql.antlr,
 org.hibernate.hql.ast,
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec,
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree,
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.util,
 org.hibernate.hql.classic,
 org.hibernate.id,
 org.hibernate.id.enhanced,
 org.hibernate.id.insert,
 org.hibernate.impl,
 org.hibernate.intercept,
 org.hibernate.intercept.cglib,
 org.hibernate.intercept.javassist,
 org.hibernate.jdbc,
 org.hibernate.jmx,
 org.hibernate.loader,
 org.hibernate.loader.collection,
 org.hibernate.loader.criteria,
 org.hibernate.loader.custom,
 org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql,
 org.hibernate.loader.entity,
 org.hibernate.loader.hql,
 org.hibernate.lob,
 org.hibernate.mapping,
 org.hibernate.metadata,
 org.hibernate.param,
 org.hibernate.persister,
 org.hibernate.persister.collection,
 org.hibernate.persister.entity,
 org.hibernate.pretty,
 org.hibernate.property,
 org.hibernate.proxy,
 org.hibernate.proxy.dom4j,
 org.hibernate.proxy.map,
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo,
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib,
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist,
 org.hibernate.secure,
 org.hibernate.sql,
 org.hibernate.stat,
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl,
 org.hibernate.tool.instrument,
 org.hibernate.tool.instrument.cglib,
 org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist,
 org.hibernate.transaction,
 org.hibernate.transform,
 org.hibernate.tuple,
 org.hibernate.tuple.component,
 org.hibernate.tuple.entity,
 org.hibernate.type,
 org.hibernate.usertype,
 org.hibernate.util,
 org.company.dao.exceptions,
 org.company.dao.util,
 org.company.edbdao.membercontractlookup.actions,
 org.company.edbdao.membercontractlookup.entities,
 org.company.edbdao.membercontractlookup.util,
 org.company.member.eligibility,
 org.company.memelig.contract,
 org.company.schema.member.eligibility,
 org.company.schema.member.eligibility.impl,
 org.company.services.memelig.actions,
 org.company.services.memelig.entities,
 org.company.services.mempick.soap,
 org.company.wsdl.Member.eligibility,
 org.jasypt.commons,
 org.jasypt.digest,
 org.jasypt.digest.config,
 org.jasypt.encryption,
 org.jasypt.encryption.pbe,
 org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config,
 org.jasypt.exceptions,
 org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider,
 org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor,
 org.jasypt.hibernate.type,
 org.jasypt.intf.cli,
 org.jasypt.intf.service,
 org.jasypt.normalization,
 org.jasypt.properties,
 org.jasypt.salt,
 org.jasypt.spring.properties,
 org.jasypt.spring.security,
 org.jasypt.spring.security2,
 org.jasypt.spring.security3,
 org.jasypt.util.binary,
 org.jasypt.util.digest,
 org.jasypt.util.numeric,
 org.jasypt.util.password,
 org.jasypt.util.text,
 org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig,
 org.jasypt.wicket,
 org.objectweb.asm,
 org.objectweb.asm.attrs,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.element.http_3A_2F_company_2Eorg_2Fschema_2FMember_2Feligibility,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.javaname.org.company.schema.member.eligibility,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.namespace._nons,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.namespace.http_3A_2F_company_2Eorg_2Fschema_2FMember_2Feligibility,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.src,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.src.URI_SHA_1_6E1E853D21CD791E29BB326D93BCA1D8052ABDA6,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s6A0AFA34988024282BA345D50C8613FE,
 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.type.http_3A_2F_company_2Eorg_2Fschema_2FMember_2Feligibility,
 unit.test
Require-Bundle: com.tibco.tpcl.org.apache.xmlbeans,com.tibco.neo.org.osoa.sca,com.tibco.tpcl.javax.annotation,com.tibco.matrix.java.annotations
Import-Package: org.apache.log4j
```

Please do let me know if you guys need anything else
Please excuse me for any error , this being my first stack overflow post

Thanks in advance
-B

Comment: So it seems that the service monitoring jar is used but the server where this SOAP endpoint is exposed. There have been some changes in the `service monitoring` that require the SOAP endpoint to be re-compiled with the new version.